# Pycharm plugin for attrs?

Tags: python, pycharm

[attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) is a useful package for reducing boilerplate. Example:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    a_number = attr.ib(default=42)
    list2_of_numbers = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(list))
```

PyCharm does not offer code completion for the generated `__init__` method, is there a plugin that can do this? Or some other work around?

Comment: Turn on code inspection at runtime or add type annotations.

Comment: @jakob-bowyer How doesn code inspection at runtime help here?
For me, missing pycharm code completion is why I don't use attrs.

Comment: Because code completion is filled in the first time your code is executed.

Comment: I created ticket for attrs support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26354

Comment: Anyone interested, pls go to jetbrains ticket and click voters. :D

Answer (score 5):

**Update Aug 2018** - As per [Hynek's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51572491/5567657), attrs support is in [PyCharm 2018.2](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#toc-2018-2). I'm a month late to the party as I haven't been working in Python much lately...

My original answer is as follows, although it only applies if you are on PyCharm 2018.1 or lower...

---

The only workaround I'm aware of (as of PyCharm 2017.2.4) is to define a redundant `__init__` in the class declaration. PyCharm's code completion picks up this method ok, but at runtime the attrs-generated `__init__` will override it. For example (with [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)):

```
import attr
from typing import List, Optional


@attr.s
class SomeClass:

    def __init__(self, a_number: int = 42,
                 list2_of_numbers : Optional[List[int]] = None) -> None:
        ...

    a_number: int = attr.ib(default=42)
    list2_of_numbers: List[int] = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(list))
```

[PyCharm code completion screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giLG7.png)

I also tried using a stub file to remove the dummy `__init__` out of the class declaration, with a view to deleting the .pyi if this is ever supported, but it didn't work.

Of course, this kind of defeats the purpose of using attrs in the first place (i.e. reducing class declaration boilerplate, aiding maintainability etc.)

If you add, remove or amend an attr.ib(), you'll need to remember to manually update the `__init__` signature which is antithetical to attrs' philosophy.

FYI, Jonas Obrist [tweeted one of the Jetbrains Devs](https://twitter.com/ojiidotch/status/892289599413731328) about attrs support earlier in the year regarding the 2017.3 release, so fingers crossed...

**EDIT**

Actually, there is a *slightly* more palatable workaround. Just pass `init=False` to `attr.s` and define your `__init__` method as you normally would. You're still not leveraging the *full* magic of attrs, but hey... it's better than nothing.

Take care to intialize your default values in your manual `__init__` rather than the attr.ib declaration against the class. As per [the docs](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html), the attr.ib's default value will only be initialised inside an attrs-generated `__init__`.

Aside from that, you still get your other dunder methods, validation, and all the other goodness as far as I can tell.

```
import attr
from typing import List, Optional


@attr.s(init=False)
class SomeClass:

    a_number: int = attr.ib()
    list2_of_numbers: List[int] = attr.ib()

    def __init__(self, a_number: int = 42,
                 list2_of_numbers : Optional[List[int]] = None) -> None:
        self.a_number: int = a_number
        self.list2_of_numbers: List[int] = list2_of_numbers or []
        # Replicate behaviour of attrs-generated __init__
        attr.validate(self)
```

Answer (score 3):

Good news: PyCharm 2018.2 has added support for attrs.

Comment: Any details or source? I just get "Unexpected argument(s)" warnings on the generated `__init__` calls.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some interesting developments lately (early '18) on this front:

- an attrs PR to [add PEP 484 stubs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/pull/238), which are recognized by PyCharm (but does not add support for `__init__`, and `cmp` special methods)
- a python typeshed PR to [add those stubs to the official third-party collection](https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/1838)
- a mypy PR to [add support for attrs special methods](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/4397)
- [a ticket for adding this feature to PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26354) (mentioned above) is getting a lot of votes (add yours!)
- [PyCharm 2018.1 EAP2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/01/pycharm-2018-1-eap-2/) added support for [dataclasses](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/), which is a new module coming in the python 3.7 standard library that is heavily inspired by `attrs`

Expect a number of these issues to be resolved in the next few months. Hopefully all of them!

Comment: attrs support included in Pycharm 2018.2, which will be released soon. :P